# Word for "not understandable"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that conveys something is "not understandable". For instance:

> The message was staticky and corrupted, making it **not understandable**.

"Not understandable" sounds strange and like a double negative. I'm looking for a single word to take the place.

Some results suggest "bizarre" and "alien", but that's not what I'm going for. The speaker knows what it is, but can't understand it.

Comment: Your sample sentence and the elaboration below seem to be incompatible. If the speaker *knows what it is*, by definition, it is *understood*. In that situation, perhaps the speaker *understands but can't *express it*. Can you please elaborate on what you mean when you say, "The speaker knows what it is"?

Comment: Try [gibberish](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gibberish).

Comment: (Synonyms: abracadabra, babble, blabber, burble, double Dutch, double-talk, drivel, gabble, gibber, jabber, jabberwocky, mumbo jumbo, nonsense, prattle, slobber, blah (also blah-blah), hocus-pocus, hokeypokey, twaddle; chatter, gab, patter, prate, tattle, twitter; cackle, clack, clatter.)

Comment: @Lawrence I think the idea here is that the speaker knows that it is message but cannot understand what it means.

Comment: I find it incomprehensible that no one who posted an answer bothered to provide a reference. Reprehensible!

Comment: @ab2 - I did for my comment above.

Comment: @Hot Licks Post your comment as an answer!  (Maybe with a bit of flesh on the skeleton.)  Let me know if you do, and I'll upvote it.

Comment: What about 'vague'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most apt word I suggest is ***incomprehensible***, but with ***unintelligible*** as a close second. However the latter has a slightly different sense, and is a bit stronger.

Comment: This answer was posted before the one at the top.  They are identical and still one of them got a downvote while the other got an upvote.  Does it make sense?

Comment: @Centaurus No, I'm confused too. Although in this case I usually accept the one answered first if both are identical.

Comment: @Centaurus I'm not the downvoter, but this answer doesn't contain a definition. Both answers (edit: all of the current answers) would be improved by a link to a definition source.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI I know I would, if it were up to me.

Comment: @NVZ Thank you for your support as regards the timing, but I am not sure I agree with your editing. To me *understand* and *comprehend* mean to all intents the same thing. So why does the negative of one become *not comprehensible* and the other *unintelligible*? However, *intelligible* and its antithesis seem to be describing something slightly different.

Comment: @WS2 feel free to roll back the edit, I just copy pasted from the dictionary with zero thoughts put into it, only to save you from the LQ queue. :)

Answer (score 8):

Yep, **incomprehensible** is the best word, it means 'not understandable' but is more concise and less awkward.

Comment: +1 I like your answer, but *the best word* seems a bit presumptuous. We also try to give formal definitions of the words we propose with a cite and a link to the source.

Answer (score 4):

'Unintelligible' means 'impossible to understand'.

Comment: This is the better answer for the OP's example. Unintelligible usually refers to a communication that made sense but was corrupted, by static in the OP's case. Incomprehensible usually refers to a communication that made no sense to start with.

Comment: In future, please include a reference and link (if the reference is online) in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

or "garbled" for garbled speech.

Comment: +1, but please provide references such as dictionary entries.

Answer (score 0):

Another candidate might be *indecipherable*.